# naturopathy Medicine which have alcohol is Halal or haram

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, medical

As Salam O Alaikum Brother,

My name is Amer and I have question regarding consuming Medicine which have alcohol.
I knew there are different post which says consuming Medicine which has little amount of alcohol for medical reason is allowed but below is my scenario.

I have medical issue and there's no cure in Allopathic / Homeopathic expect surgery and that will lead to greater complication in the future for whole life.

There are some naturopathy which says to prepare a medicine ( 1 litre of Vodka and 50 Walnut filament and store for 3 weeks in dark place )
and have 2 Tea spoon every day three time. They are claiming this is the perfect medicine and will always work and lots of people agreed. There are also people in Muslim world also used it.

Need brother advice, should I go ahead as this is the Medicine and very low amount of intake.

Wa Salam.

Comment: If you can elaborate on where you live and what climate of that area, it would be useful. Also you have not mentioned the medical issue you suffer from.

Answer (score 2):

The smaller quantity does not make a difference:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: If a large amount of anything causes intoxication, a small amount of it is prohibited. ([Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/27/13))

I suggest that you do your research about naturopathy since most of it is false, and it is not scientific. Especially considering it is asking you to do something prohibited.

Unless, a truly qualified doctor gives you such a suggestion based on hard science, I do not think doing prohibited things for the off chance that it will cure you is halal.